# Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**TL;DR:** I'm trying to use the new `react-hooks` api, but I keep getting an Invariant Violation error when calling the `setState` hook, but it keeps failing.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// type State = {
//   heading: string;
// }

const Text = () => {
  const initialState = 'Heading'.toUpperCase();

  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(initialState);

  return (
    <header>
      <h1>
        {setHeading('Brussels')};
        {heading}
      </h1>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Text;
```

Comment: You should not be calling `setHeading` without any event. It will cause infinite rendering. Apart from that, What are the version of `react` and `react-dom`? Also, make sure that you have only one copy of the react.

Comment: do you use hot reload? it transforms functional components into class under the hood. check [issue at react repo](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling setHeading("Brussel") will cause re rendering again and again which in turns result in an infinite loop, to prevent that you need an event to change the header from "Heading" to "Brussels".
Below code might help you

```
const Text = () => {
const initialState= 'Heading'.toUpperCase();
const [heading, setHeading] = useState(initialState);  
return (
 <header>
    <h1>
    {heading}
    <button onClick= {() =>{setHeading("Brussel")}}>ChangeName</button>
    </h1>
    </header>
);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

If you think back in the class component version, your code is calling `this.setState` in the `render()` which will trigger another render, and call `this.setState` again, and the cycle repeats, and you'll get the error:

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

You wouldn't call `this.setState` directly in your render method and neither should you do that using hooks.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here, but I think what you want is to set the name only once, which you would do in `componentDidMount`, and you can use the `useEffect` hook to achieve that.

Or if you want "Brussels" to be the initial state, pass it as the value into `useState()`.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Text = () => {
  const initialState = 'Heading'.toUpperCase();
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(initialState);
  useEffect(() => {
    setHeading('Brussels');
  }, []); // Pass in empty array to simulate componentDidMount.
  
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>
        {heading}
      </h1>
    </header>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Text />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I think this question was already correctly and descriptively answered by @jShubh and and instead of adding the same answer, you could have upvoted his answer

Comment: The reasons are the same but my answer elaborates on the problem and provides a suggestion based on what I think the asker is trying to achieve. How are the answers the same? I don't think the asker intended to add a button/event handler to the code.

Comment: @YangshunTay, your answered in addition to the the one provided by `@jShubh` helped with my problem. I decided to marked `@jShubh's` answer correct, cause he sent it first, even though yours was more detailed and shone some light onto some of my questions..

Thanks peeps ✌️

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my react version in a certain project so I can use hooks until then I had the same issue and based on the docs the error occurs for mismatching the version of react and react-dom. Upgrading the react-dom works for in my case.

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html